# Partitioning a weighted tree to equally weighted subtrees

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, partitioning

Input:

- a rooted tree with `n` nodes;
- each node `p` has positive integer weight `w(p)`;
- a node can have more than two children.

Problem:

- divide the tree into `k` subtrees/partitions (obviously by removing `k-1` edges);
- subtree weight `W(p)` is the weight of all the nodes in a subtree rooted at node `p`;
- all the subtrees should be weighted as evenly as possible - the difference between `min(W(p))` and `max(W(p))` should be as small as possible.

I've yet to find a suitable algorithm for this. Where should I start? Tips, instructions and pseudocode appreciated.

Comment: This seems difficult to get an exact answer for in polynomial time. For how large `n` and `k` do you need this to work, and does your partition need to be the exact optimum?

Comment: The answer can be an approximation, as long as the resulting subtrees are 'reasonably' balanced. Input: `n<500`; `k=3..10`

Answer (score 0):

Assume you can't modify the tree other than to remove edges to create subtrees.

First understand that you cannot guarantee that by simply removing edges that you will have subtrees within an arbitrary bound. You can create tree that when you split them there is no way to create subtrees within a target bound. For example:

```
a(b(c,d,e,f),g)
```

You cannot split that into two balanced sections. The best you can do is remove the edge from a to b:

a(g)  and b(c,d,e,f)

Also this criteria is a little underdefined when k > 2. What is better a split 10,10,10,1 or 10,10,6,5?

But you can come up with a method to split trees up in the most balanced way possible.

Implement you tree such that each node holds a count of all of its children. You can add this pretty efficiently to any tree. ( E.g. when you add a node you have to iterate up the chain of parent node incrementing the count. Remove a node and you iterate up subtracting from the count )

Then starting from the root iterate down, in a breadth first manner until you find a set of nodes that dominate child nodes in a way that is most balanced. I don't have an algorithm for this at the ready - but I think you can find one pretty readily.

I think something where when you want to divide into k subtrees you create an array of k tree roots. One of those nodes must always be the root of the current tree, then you iterate down looking for nodes to replace on of the k-1 candidates that improves the partitioning. You'll want some kind of terminating condition where you don't interate down to every leaf node. E.g. it never makes sense to subdivide anything by the largest candidate node.

Comment: `n` is large enough and `k` is small enough, fairly balanced partitions should be achievable. In the case of 10,10,10,1 (10-1=9) vs 10,10,6,5 (10-5=5) the latter is a better split, since 9>5 - criteria is to `minimize max(W(p))-min(W(p))`. Will take some time to process the rest.